# How to load https in WebView in Android 2.1

Tags: android, ssl, https, webview

I am loading a WebView in an Android application with the below code:

```
mWebView.loadURL("https://wat.harminson.com/html/index.html");
```

The above code is working fine in Android 2.2 and greater. But when I change my app to 2.1 I am unable to see the WebView. I am just seeing the white screen. Any suggesstions as to what might cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that your problem ?
http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/

Comment: yes you are correct because "onReceivedSslError" error is there from 2.2 onwards.But it is not there in 2.1,so it cannot proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to 2.2 (and possibly later releases, for some naughty manufacturers), Android devices had not been told to trust the "VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3" (issued in 1999), and relied instead on "Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority" (issued in 1996).

Servers that are offering a certificate chain wherein their own certificate is signed by G5, G5 is signed by G3, and G3 is self-signed, fail on Android 2.1 and earlier because 21st century browsers are expected to know that they should trust G3.

You can check your server's certificate chain by using a desktop browser and clicking on the padlock icon - ask to see certificate details, it'll usually show you a tree of certificate trust.

If your server is offering a certificate chain that ends with the self-signed G3 certificate, you need to have it changed so instead of the self-signed G3 certificate, it offers the G3 certificate signed by the 1996 certificate that Android 2.1 and earlier devices know about.

https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/mpki-for-ssl-support/index?page=content&id=SO17511&actp=AGENT_REFERAL

Fixing this meant that the 2.1 and 1.6 devices I tried became happy with the server.

I speculate that devices with some version of the G3 certificate built in will continue to trust G5 without reference to the G3 in the server-proffered certificate chain, so it *should* be OK when the 1996 certificate expires in 2028.